# Convert column type from varchar() to time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why I keep getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

My SQL code:

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(time, open_time) AS new_time
FROM museum_hours
```

`open_time` column is defined as `varchar(max)`.

I tried `CAST()` as well and I'm getting the same error!

Comment: Please also share the data in open_time

Comment: You could use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` to get back a `NULL` (instead of an exception happening) if the source data is not a valid time value

Comment: Clearly, the string data, which you have not provided, is not in a valid format. Aside, why would you define a column to store up to 2gb of data if you only need a few characters that represent a time?

Comment: This is the format in open_time>>10:00:AM >>351 rows

Comment: Please edit your question and add the missing detail.

Comment: Why are you using a `varchar(MAX)` to store a *time*? What "time" is going to be *over* 8,000 characters long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string value `'10:00:AM'` is *not* a valid time format; however `'10:00 AM'` is, note there is no colon preceding AM/PM.

Therefore you need to remove the erroneous colon:

```
select try_convert(Time, Stuff(open_time, 6, 1, ' ')) new_time
from museum_hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are trying to convert null or non convertable strings. try these options below or use Try_cast().

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(time, open_time) AS new_time
FROM museum_hours
WHERE ISDATE(open_time) = 1
```

or

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(time, open_time) AS new_time
FROM museum_hours
WHERE open_time is not null
```

Comment: Not without removing the invalid `:`